# How would I convert words to numbers in python 3 (own keys and values)?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a Python 3 script that will take words in a text file and convert them into numbers (my own, not ASCII, so no ord function). I have assigned each letter to an integer and would like each word to be the sum of its letters' numerical value. The goal is to group each word with the same numerical value into a dictionary. I am having great trouble recombining the split words as numbers and adding them together. I am completely stuck with this script (it is not complete yet.

**Btw, I know the easier way of creating the l_n dictionary below, but since I've already written it out, I am a little lazy to change it for now, but will do so after the completion of the script.

```
l_n = {
    "A": 1, "a": 1,
    "B": 2, "b": 2,
    "C": 3, "c": 3,
    "D": 4, "d": 4,
    "E": 5, "e": 5,
    "F": 6, "f": 6,
    "G": 7, "g": 7,
    "H": 8, "h": 8,
    "I": 9, "i": 9,
    "J": 10, "j": 10,
    "K": 11, "k": 11,
    "L": 12, "l": 12,
    "M": 13, "m": 13,
    "N": 14, "n": 14,
    "O": 15, "o": 15,
    "P": 16, "p": 16,
    "Q": 17, "q": 17,
    "R": 18, "r": 18,
    "S": 19, "s": 19,
    "T": 20, "t": 20,
    "U": 21, "u": 21,
    "V": 22, "v": 22,
    "W": 23, "w": 23,
    "X": 24, "x": 24,
    "Y": 25, "y": 25,
    "Z": 26, "z": 26,
    }

words_list = []

def read_words(file):
    opened_file = open(file, "r")
    contents = opened_file.readlines()

    for i in range(len(contents)):
        words_list.extend(contents[i].split())

    opened_file.close()

    return words_list

read_words("file1.txt")
new_words_list = list(set(words_list))

numbers_list = []
w_n = {}

def words_to_numbers(new_words_list, l_n):
    local_list = new_words_list[:]
    local_number_list = []

    for word in local_list:
        local_number_list.append(word.split())
        for key in l_n:
            local_number_list = local_number_list.replace( **#I am stuck on the logic in this section.**

words_to_numbers(new_words_list, l_n)
print(local_list)
```

I've tried looking for an answer on stackoverflow but was unable to find an answer.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: so  why not just have a counter that increments by the value  for each letter?

Comment: Thank you all for your excellent answers. This was my first question on stackoverflow; and being a beginner programmer, I have some difficulty understanding the answers (not used to list/dictionary comprehension for example) so it was hard to select a "best" answer. I will try out your solutions and learn from them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to handle punctuation but you just need to sum the value of each words letters and group them which you can do with a defaultdict:

```
lines = """am writing a Python script that will take words in a text file and convert them into numbers (my own, not ASCII, so no ord function).
I have assigned each letter to an integer and would like each word to be the sum of its letters' numerical value.
The goal is to group each word with the same numerical value into a dictionary.
I am having great trouble recombining the split words as numbers and adding them together"""

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for line in lines.splitlines():
    for word in line.split():
        d[sum(l_n.get(ch,0) for ch in word)].append(word)
```

Output:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(dict(d))
{1: ['a', 'a', 'a'],
 7: ['be'],
 9: ['I', 'I'],
 14: ['am', 'am'],
 15: ['an'],
 17: ['each', 'each', 'each'],
 19: ['and', 'and', 'and'],
 20: ['as'],
 21: ['of'],
 23: ['in'],
 28: ['is'],
 29: ['no'],
 32: ['file'],
 33: ['the', 'The', 'the', 'the'],
 34: ['so'],
 35: ['to', 'to', 'goal', 'to'],
 36: ['have'],
 37: ['take', 'ord', 'like'],
 38: ['(my', 'same'],
 39: ['adding'],
 41: ['ASCII,'],
 46: ['them', 'them'],
 48: ['its'],
 49: ['that', 'not'],
 51: ['great'],
 52: ['own,'],
 53: ['sum'],
 56: ['will'],
 58: ['into', 'into'],
 60: ['word', 'word', 'with'],
 61: ['value.', 'value', 'having'],
 69: ['text'],
 75: ['would'],
 76: ['split'],
 77: ['group'],
 78: ['assigned', 'integer'],
 79: ['words', 'words'],
 80: ['letter'],
 85: ['script'],
 92: ['numbers', 'numbers'],
 93: ['trouble'],
 96: ['numerical', 'numerical'],
 97: ['convert'],
 98: ['Python', 'together'],
 99: ["letters'"],
 100: ['writing'],
 102: ['function).'],
 109: ['recombining'],
 118: ['dictionary.']}
```

`sum(l_n.get(ch,0) for ch in word)` gets the sum of all the letters in the word, we use that as the key and just append the word as the value. The defaultdict handles repeated keys so we end you with all the words that have the same sum grouped in lists.

Also as John commented you can simply store a set of lowercase letters in the dict and call `.lower` `sum(l_n.get(ch,0) for ch in word.lower())`

If you want to remove all punctuation you can use `str.translate`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from string import punctuation
d = defaultdict(list)
for line in lines.splitlines():
    for word in line.split():
        word = word.translate(None,punctuation)
        d[sum(l_n.get(ch,0) for ch in word)].append(word)
```

Which would output:

```
{1: ['a', 'a', 'a'],
 7: ['be'],
 9: ['I', 'I'],
 14: ['am', 'am'],
 15: ['an'],
 17: ['each', 'each', 'each'],
 19: ['and', 'and', 'and'],
 20: ['as'],
 21: ['of'],
 23: ['in'],
 28: ['is'],
 29: ['no'],
 32: ['file'],
 33: ['the', 'The', 'the', 'the'],
 34: ['so'],
 35: ['to', 'to', 'goal', 'to'],
 36: ['have'],
 37: ['take', 'ord', 'like'],
 38: ['my', 'same'],
 39: ['adding'],
 41: ['ASCII'],
 46: ['them', 'them'],
 48: ['its'],
 49: ['that', 'not'],
 51: ['great'],
 52: ['own'],
 53: ['sum'],
 56: ['will'],
 58: ['into', 'into'],
 60: ['word', 'word', 'with'],
 61: ['value', 'value', 'having'],
 69: ['text'],
 75: ['would'],
 76: ['split'],
 77: ['group'],
 78: ['assigned', 'integer'],
 79: ['words', 'words'],
 80: ['letter'],
 85: ['script'],
 92: ['numbers', 'numbers'],
 93: ['trouble'],
 96: ['numerical', 'numerical'],
 97: ['convert'],
 98: ['Python', 'together'],
 99: ['letters'],
 100: ['writing'],
 102: ['function'],
 109: ['recombining'],
 118: ['dictionary']}
```

If you don't want duplicate words appearing then use a set:

```
d = defaultdict(set)
....
d[sum(l_n.get(ch,0) for ch in word)].add(word)
```

Comment: +1 for keeping the words with their counts, that way its an easy mapping incase all the op wants is just a bunch of numbers. btw you could also use lower on the letters so the `l_n` only needs to have one set of the letters of the alphabet

Comment: @JohnRuddell, yep, lower would do the trick. Did not see they actaully had the same value

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer. I don't understand the collections module too much but am reading about it now. I like how the output is in numerical order. Due to my confusion about the module you used, I've implemented the third answer's code (with my own tweaking) instead for now- but it gave me the result in an un-ordered fashion (hence, your way would be a little more useful.)

Answer (score 1):

i think this is also a good way for doing this

```
import string
letters = string.lowercase
def give_sum(str):
    ans = 0

    for i in str:
        if i.lower() in letters:
            value = letters.find(i.lower()) + 1
            ans += value
    return ans

w_n = {}
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        w_n[give_sum(line)] = [line]
print w_n
```

ps: optimize the code according to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned , this is not the best way but if  we code exactly in your way , this would be the completed code,i checked it and it works.
you need to change your  `def words_to_numbers` code and calculate values of each string according to your `l_n` dictionary which in that, keys are strings and values are lists.

```
l_n = {
    "A": 1, "a": 1,
    "B": 2, "b": 2,
    "C": 3, "c": 3,
    "D": 4, "d": 4,
    "E": 5, "e": 5,
    "F": 6, "f": 6,
    "G": 7, "g": 7,
    "H": 8, "h": 8,
    "I": 9, "i": 9,
    "J": 10, "j": 10,
    "K": 11, "k": 11,
    "L": 12, "l": 12,
    "M": 13, "m": 13,
    "N": 14, "n": 14,
    "O": 15, "o": 15,
    "P": 16, "p": 16,
    "Q": 17, "q": 17,
    "R": 18, "r": 18,
    "S": 19, "s": 19,
    "T": 20, "t": 20,
    "U": 21, "u": 21,
    "V": 22, "v": 22,
    "W": 23, "w": 23,
    "X": 24, "x": 24,
    "Y": 25, "y": 25,
    "Z": 26, "z": 26,
    }

words_list = []

def read_words(file):
    opened_file = open(file, "r")
    contents = opened_file.readlines()

    for i in range(len(contents)):
        words_list.extend(contents[i].split())

    opened_file.close()

    return words_list

read_words("file1.txt")
new_words_list = list(set(words_list))

print "new_word_list",new_words_list
numbers_list = []
w_n = {}


def words_to_numbers(new_words_list,l_n):
    local_list = new_words_list[:]
    for word in local_list:
        tmp = 0
        for ch in word:
            tmp += l_n[ch]
        if str(tmp) in w_n:
            w_n[str(tmp)].append(word)
        else:
            tmp_lis = []
            tmp_lis.append(word)
            w_n[str(tmp)] = tmp_lis

    return w_n

print "the_answer_is ==> ",words_to_numbers(new_words_list,l_n)
```

Comment: the code you posted isn't any different than the OP's? how is it a working solution if thats the case?

Comment: Pay more attention and you'll find diffs :) !! And you can run both to check that if it works or not :)
@JohnRuddell

Comment: @ImanMirzadeh: how about you explain what changed? That way future visitors don't have to go hunt for the differences. This is not a milk carton time passing game here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You're right ! ;)

Comment: I used this code (modified it slightly) and it worked well. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Byte : happy for helping you :) ! please vote up my ans for next people to see this works ;)